# Is it possible to use Meteor.Call to retrieve data from MongoDB?

Tags: cordova, meteor

I managed to create an helper that returns the data of a Collection once it's published from the server.

However I don't manage to **retrieve the data by using Meteor.call (i.e. Collection server-side).**

This is my code:

**client/template.html**

```
<template name="showScannedData">
     <!- .... more code -->
    {{myUserNetId}}
</template>
```

**client/helpers.js** (the one that works)

```
Template.showScannedData.helpers({
    'myUserNetId': function(){
       return Individuals.findOne().netId; // WORKS
    }
});
```

**client/helpers.js** (the one that does **not** work, i.e. blank output)

```
Template.showScannedData.helpers({
      return Meteor.call('getmyUserNetId', function(err,res){
          return res;
      });
    }
});
```

**server/db_methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    getmyUserNetId: function(){
        return Individuals.findOne({}).netId;
    }
})
```

Comment: You are returning Meteor.call and its empty at time of call, you need to return some value in callback

Comment: Your helper still needs to be formatted in the way your first one is. Moreover, you cannot synchronously return an asynchronous value. You will need to set a Session variable or any ReactiveVar in the callback of the Meteor.call()